# need to apply filter in my lambda function,but getting error function is not iterable

Tags: python, lambda, filter

Need to filter lambda function so that it can give only even result. please help i am a beginner.

```
list_one = [1,2,3,4]

list_two = [5,6,7,8]

a = lambda *b :[sum(j)/len(j) for j in zip(*b)] 
output-->[5,6,7,8] without applying filter


b = filter((a % 2 == 0),(list_one,list_two))

want output [6,8] after applying filter method
```

Comment: Can you please post the error message?

Comment: function is not iterable

Comment: Please edit your question to include what you are trying to do and what is the expected output.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to pass a function and an iterable to the filter.

the function is filtering elements that match a condition.

The iterable is the output of a:

```
b = filter(lambda e: e%2==0, a(list_one, list_two))
```

Comment: d = filter(lambda w : w%2 == 0, (map((lambda s:s*2), (lambda *b : [sum(j)/2 for j in zip(*b)]))))
print(list(d(li1,list2)))   what am i doing wrong. again say function function is not iterable